# Am I expected to manually create the trunk/ and branches/ folders w/ Subversion, or are those folders created by themselves?

Tags: svn, version-control

I am having some trouble grasping something pretty simple about subversion:

If I want to have a subversion repo with a trunk and several branches, do I have to manually create the `trunk/` and `branches/` folders, and from then on it's my responsibility to keep everything tidy and in the correct place?

I can give a concrete example to back up the above question:

> Let's say I've created a Subversion
>   repository and I've checked it out to
>   some folder `F`.
>
> `F` is at this moment empty (it
>   actually has that .svn folder, but
>   that hardly matters). I add a couple
>   of files to `F` and hit commit.
>
> Now I want to create a branch `B`. I
>   (through Tortoise) hit the Branch
>   command, but it is asking me for a
>   folder to which to copy my data. I
>   don't have at the moment any folder to
>   which copy the data!

I was introduced to branching in version control systems by git, so my thought process is shaped by the way git branching system works.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create `/branch`, `/tag`, and `/trunk` folders.  And yes, it's your responsibility after that to put things in the appropriate place.

Branches aren't special in SVN; you can think of trunk as a branch.

Tags *are* special.  Those should be labeled, read-only snapshots of code that was deployed.

Comment: Though it should be noted that some SVN clients (e.g. TortoiseSVN, Subclipse) will help you by using appropriate folders by default, and warning about possible mistakes. E.g., Subclipse will warn you if you try to commit into a tag.

Comment: One more question: does that mean that contrary to what happens with git, subversion has no core concept of branch? The way you put it, it seems branches in subversion are just something we humans call to special folders we have in our repo.

Comment: One more question: ... the answer to that would be yes, which is why tools mentioned by sleske warn you about "mistakes" but will not stop you doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, branches/tags in SVN are not special (unlike other version control systems like ClearCase etc). That's just a way to organize the stuff and make it conform to standards.

Like it's been said earlier, when you create a repository, it's your responsibility to create the tags/branches/release folders.